Wrapping the text of list items within container
I am having issues wrapping the text of my list item that is within my container.
Background:
I have a container in my PowerApp titled "conTasksPane"

On the container I have Wrap enabled

The list properties do not have a "Wrap" option to toggle but I have set the "AlignInContainer" to be set by container, also tried modifying layout min Width

How can I achieve my goal of wrapping the text of the list items?

you are using tab list control in your example. Instead, use the listbox control. It's fundamentally the same and it allows wrap. Good day!!

So I copied the settings from my tab list control to a listbox control, but isn't returning same values, how do I need to switch the structure? As you can see the tab list control has a control underneath it that puts the title. Not sure how to accomplish same thing with listbox

Nevermind! I see that the listBox has a value column in the properties setting page.

Sadly, you currently cannot achieve that with these controls.

like you said, tablist has no wrap property.
container has wrap property, but it has nothing to do with the text in the conatainer's children. Instead, if the child elements' combined height exceeds the container's height, enabling wrap will organize the children into columns inside the container (or rows if the container is horizontal).

If available, use flexible height gallery with text labels. Wrap on text labels will achieve the desired layout.
